# How to handle vendors without typings in TypeScript?

Tags: typescript

I'm thinking about switching from native JS to TS for an application I'm developing. I've created a new branch to test things - Typescript itself seems to be fine for it, but there's one major problem I'm facing: some vendors I'm using do not have any or just outdated definition files.

The question now is: how to handle missing defintion files?

I could do something like

```
declare var sails: any;
```

but is this really a good idea?

Answer (score 1):

```
declare var sails: any;
```

Is a hack. It's good to get yourself going, or to let you try a library to see if it will actually work, but your best bet is to be explicit. (Any time you have `: any` in your project, it should be a red flag that you need to fix something - but realistically almost everyone has an `any` or two (or more) floating around). That being said: something as big as sails should **not** be an `any`.

So, what can you do?

**Look on [DefinitelyTyped](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped)**

If you are using Typescript 2, you can install *most* of the definitions from definitely typed with npm via

```
npm i -g @types/thing-you-want
```

(unfortunately, it doesn't look like Sails is on DefinitelyTyped)

You can also try googling to see if anyone else has written a definition file that's *not* on definitely typed but that still works.

Be prepared though, even definitely typed is not guaranteed to be correct and may need massaging.

**Write your definitions as you need them**

This may be what you are up against. This is certainly not as thorough, but it will usually get you where you need to go. Look up the documentation for the portion of the API you need and add those definitions to your `.d.ts` file.

If you go about it this way, it's less overwhelming and you can contribute your work to DefintielyTyped when you are finished if you are so inclined :).

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Sails, for example, doesn't have typings for the current version (at least I didn't find anything). If I face one or two other libraries or frameworks which doesn't have any definitons I'd spent a serious amount of time in writing definitions... which sounds like a pretty big disadvantage, since it's a serious time loss :/

Comment: @nehalist I think a big reason sails is missing TS support is because of the CLI. When typescript happens it will probably come from the guys maintaining the framework, rather than the community. In the mean-time, you can try checking out [flow](https://flowtype.org/) which is a bit more forgiving in situations like this.

Comment: One final thought: I'd advise you to try not to let this discourage future evaluations of Typescript. I agree that, depending on the size of your project (and because you are using sails) it might be difficult to work Typescript in now - starting with Typescript is generally much easier than converting (especially if your libraries are supported).

Comment: I'm not discouraged about using TS, just trying to find a solution - I'm still thinking that using TypeScript for my project would be a good choice. Is using the `any` hack a solution as long as there are no (sails) definitions? Not using TS just because two or three libs of many have no definitions sounds a bit wrong.

Comment: `any` types introduce risk, and the more you use them the more risk they introduce (obviously) - but if you find that you aren't interacting with sails directly much, I say go for it. You could also always go back and add sails definitions yourself later (if you find that Typescript has help in other places) or add the definitions when they are added to the package directly.